# Angular HttpClient Cannot detect Custom Headers

Tags: angular

I am trying to get value of custom header sent by API but i cannot get the value of header using angular httpclient

the following is the sample code i use

```
getUsers(pageNumber? , pageSize?): Observable<PaginatedResult<IUser[]>> {
    const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<IUser[]> = new PaginatedResult<IUser[]>();
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    if (pageNumber != null) {
      params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);
    }
    if (pageSize != null) {
      params = params.append('pageSize', pageSize);
    }
    return this.httpClient.get<IUser[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users', {observe: 'response', params: params})
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        paginatedResult.result = response.body;

        if (response.headers.get('Pagination') != null) {

          paginatedResult.paginationInfo = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('Pagination'));

        }
        return paginatedResult;
      })
    );
  }
```

this line "(response.headers.get('Pagination')" always return null although "Pagination" header is marked "Access-Control-Expose-Header"

as in the following screenshot

[Pagination Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQG0.png)

Comment: It's [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) (with an `s`).

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working